# Finding if a graph contains an even cycle

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am looking for a simple boolean-like function which could check if a graph contains [an even cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph#Terminology). I'm aware there is ExtractCycles but I'm looking for a true/false output than a list of cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
evenCycleTest[g_: Graph] := AnyTrue[Flatten@FindCycle[g, #] & /@ Range[2, VertexCount[g], 2], # != {} &]
```

Examples:

```
g = Graph[RandomGraph[{20, 49}]];

evenCycleTest[g]
```

True

```
h = StarGraph[20];

evenCycleTest[h]
```

False